# No longer able to edit tag wikis

Tags: support, wiki, editing

Given the new tags page, tag wikis are yet more valuable and important.  But there has been a regression in our ability to edit them.

I created the authentication tag wiki a while ago, and am still the top answerer: https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/authentication/topusers

I just tried to update it, but now my edit needs to be approved, even though I have over 2200 reputation.  "You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed."  It says I now need "trusted user" permissions (4000 reputation).

Ironically it offers to let me approve other edits on tags where I have little rep, like forensics.  Yet when I do so, and it says the approval worked, it still shows as "needs approval".  **Update** I then tried to reproduce this, and seem to have succeeded in approving either that edit or the related edit to the tax excerpt - so perhaps I somehow misinterpreted what happened before.  So at this point I can approve other tag wiki edits, but not make one of my own....

C.v. [Should we reduce the limits for editing the tag wiki? - IT Security Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/should-we-reduce-the-limits-for-editing-the-tag-wiki)

Comment: See also recent discussion by @waffles of a related recent change: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83092/bug-tag-wiki-edit-privileges-arent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you reach "trusted user" privilege (normally 10k on public sites, but reduced for beta), all wiki edits must be suggested and approved by trusted users and/or community moderator.

This system of suggested wiki edits replaces the byzantine system we had before, so I consider it a distinct improvement...

Comment: Seems like having approval level that high will slow down development of tag wikis for betas.  So as with the other linked issue, I think the limits should be reduced.  Having clarity on tags early on in beta helps later on.

Comment: @neal the community mods have a really obnoxious indicator on every page until that edit suggestion queue is cleared, so unless your pro-tem community moderators are not on the site *at all* I don't expect this to be a problem in practice.

Comment: Well, it does slow things down and introduce impedance.   Hmm - lots more people than that can suggest, right?  And note that it seems that anyone with 1500 rep can approve, so what this change accomplishes is either trusted user/mod approval, or tag review by someone else with moderate level of rep.